# GAE on linux CI server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jenkins, continuous-integration, nosetests

Folks, we're trying to setup the CI testing environment to test our GAE app. Our CI server runs on linux and Jenkins on top of that. Locally nosetests and nosegunit work fantastic; however, on the CI server since there aren't any installers per se, the GAE python modules aren't "registered" and can't be found by nose or python for that matter. Any tips how to make this setup work?

Comment: What do you mean by installers? Are you using the [devserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) or just unit-testing python code?

Comment: unit testing the python AppEngine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about unit-tests, write a setup.py file for your app with the required packages listed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='myapp',
      version='1.0',
      description='This is a cool webapp by Syrahn.',
      author='Syrahn',
      requires=['googleappengine','nosetests',], #etc
     )
```

Than, as a step of your Jenkins job, setup a virtualenv, and build and install your app into the virtualenv. This will also install the required libraries, for example:

```
virtualenv myenv
myenv/bin/python setup.py sdist 
myenv/bin/pip install mypackage.tar.gz
```

..after this you can run the unittests:

```
myenv/bin/nosetests
```

Comment: This sounds rather complicated, at least when compared how easy it is for OSX and Windows.

Comment: You previously ran a Jenkins CI on Windows and OSX?

Comment: Anyway, most of this ensures that each time you run your Jenkins job, it will do a clean install of your app, preventing deployment problems as a result of left-over files. It is always good to know what packages your application depends upon.